# retrive all data with counting per item when joining two table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, activerecord, join

I have two tables:

```
Table 1: contest_video

Table Rows: cv_id, uid, cid, cn_id, video_name, video_detail, video, image, cverify, date

Table 2: contest_vote

Table Rows: vid, cv_id, voter_id, date
```

Now I want to join these two table that will with a counting. Like total number of vote (vid) of a video(video name)

I have tried this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`contest_video`)
  LEFT JOIN `system_user`
    ON `system_user`.`id` = `contest_video`.`uid`
  LEFT JOIN `contest_vote`
    ON `contest_vote`.`cv_id` = `contest_video`.`cv_id`
WHERE `contest_video`.`cid` = '1'
ORDER BY `contest_video`.`created_date` DESC
```

But it returns only data without counting. Need experts help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

use group by and column names instead of `*`

```
SELECT
  cv_id,
  uid,
  cid,
  cn_id,
  video_name,
  video_detail,
  video,
  image,
  cverify,
  date,
  count(`contest_video`.`cv_id`) Total
FROM (`contest_video`)
  LEFT JOIN `system_user`
    ON `system_user`.`id` = `contest_video`.`uid`
  LEFT JOIN `contest_vote`
    ON `contest_vote`.`cv_id` = `contest_video`.`cv_id`
WHERE `contest_video`.`cid` = '1'
GROUP BY `contest_video`.`video_name`
ORDER BY `contest_video`.`created_date` DESC
```